# Can't get Imageflow to appear in Internet Explorer using PHP in a DIV template

Tags: php, internet-explorer, html, imageflow

The following page can be viewed in internet explorer as a standalone page :

http://http://www.kaimeramedia.com/derek/Website/cgi_new.php

so I can't understand why when I call that php into a div layer that it doesn't show up in Internet Explorer.  Chrome shows everything perfectly.  The entire site can be found at

http://www.kaimeramedia.com/derek/Website/index.php

There is simple code in the header of each page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href = "highslide.css" type="text/css"/> 
<Script src="highslide.js"type ="text/javascript"></script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="imageflow.css" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="imageflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is the location of the entire imageflow.js & highslide.js files:

http://www.kaimeramedia.com/derek/Website/imageflow.js

Any help would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
illegal character

if (imgSrc.substr(imgSrc.length-4) === ‘.png’ || imgSrc.substr(imgSrc.length-4)
index.php (line 44, col 39)
```

Your quotes are not correct on .png they should be the character ' or "

Chrome must allow them for some reason (Firefox here).

Found it with firebug, I suggest you get the chrome equivalent, I have a feeling even if it works it will tell you about it.

Comment: I found that all the quotes were incorrect in that code... I replaced them with the correct ' or "  do not know where to even find the other 2 kinds that were in there.

Comment: Tried what you suggested and inspected the elements using firebug and still can't seem to fix the black around the fading menu in Internet Explorer :(  Is the rest of the code correct?

Comment: Well I finally got that code to do what it is required, but it makes the site look even worse so that wasn't the solution, but that script is specifically to deal with the black around png files in IE when fading.  The other problem I listed here is getting Highslide to Show up in the php div layer ... all of it works in Chrome, but not entirely correctly (or at all) in Explorer.